# A web page cache confuse in node.js

Tags: node.js, authorization, browser-cache

I use `passport.js` in my node program, for authorization control,

suppose I have two page in different authorization

```
//need authorization
app.get('/admin', checkaccess, function (req, res) {

})

//doesn't need authorization
app.get('/blog', function () {

})
```

when I log in and at page `/admin`, I jump to `/blog` in the same window, then I clear the `cookie`,

it means that I can't access `/admin` any more, if I open a new window, and try to `/admin`, 
indeed I can't,

but when I use the back button in browser at the `/blog` to switch to `/admin`, it success!

Is it a cache problem?How can I stop this happend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like this should help.

```
//need authorization
app.get('/admin', checkaccess, function (req, res) {
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');


})

//doesn't need authorization
app.get('/blog', function () {

})
```